# Graceful Simple Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Wikipedia claims that all simple graphs of 4 or less vertices are graceful, but I'm not sure how this result was achieved besides drawing out 11 possible simple graphs with 4 vertices -- also not sure if it's true.

Comment: I am pretty sure there's nothing to it except checking all the cases. Note that Wikipedia is incorrectly omitting the word *connected* (which I've now fixed); there are some ungraceful graphs with $2$, $3$, and $4$ vertices that are not connected. (The problem there is that to label the vertices with distinct integers in the range $[0,m]$, you can have at most $m+1$ vertices, so we fail if we don't have enough edges.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a lot to check here. Here are vertex labelings for all the graceful graphs with $4$ vertices or fewer.

For $1$ vertex:

```
0
```

For $2$ vertices:

```
0--1
```

For $3$ vertices:

```
  2        3
 / \      / \
0   1    0---1
```

For $4$ vertices:

```
0--3    0--3    0--3    0--4    0--4    0--2    0--4
| /       /     |\      |  |    | /     |\ |    |\/|
|/       /      | \     |  |    |/      | \|    |/\|
1  2    1--2    1  2    2--1    1--3    1--5    1--6
```

There are $7$ graphs on $4$ or fewer vertices, in total, that are not graceful, all for the same reason that they have $n$ vertices and fewer than $n-1$ edges. We've got:

- The empty graph on $2$, $3$, or $4$ vertices;
- The graph with one edge on $3$ or $4$ vertices;
- The two graphs with two edges on $4$ vertices. (The edges can share a vertex or not.)